# Replacing the values in one file with the values in another file in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, csv

I am having a csv file naming `List.csv` in following format:

```
Location,IP Address,Host Name,Domain,Domain Name, User Name,Manufacturer,Model,System Type, Serial Number, Operating System,RAM (GB),Processor Type,Processor Frequency
H1,xx.xx.xx.xx,PC1,domain.com,DOMAIN,User1,LENOVO,4089AZ8,X86-based PC,L90RA96,Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ,2,Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5800,3.20GHz
H3,xx.xx.xx.xx,PC2,domain.com,DOMAIN,User2,LENOVO,4089AZ8,X86-based PC,L906W3P,Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ,2,Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5800,3.20GHz
H2,xx.xx.xx.xx,PC3,domain.com,DOMAIN,User3,LENOVO,4089A76,X86-based PC,L929410,Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ,2,Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5400,2.70GHz
H2,xx.xx.xx.xx,PC4,domain.com,DOMAIN,User4,Hewlett-Packard,Z800,x64-based PC,SGH007QT16,Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ,12,Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU W5590,3.33GHz
```

If you look at the `MODEL` column, it is bearing some values which do not interpret the name of the model. I have created another file, `model-list.csv`, which contains these values and their corresponding model names. It looks something like :

```
Manufacturer,Value,Model Name
Lenovo, 4089AZ8, ThinkCentre
Lenovo, 4089A76, ThinkCentre
HP, Z800, HP Z800 Workstation
```

I want the values in the `List.csv` file to be replaced by the corresponding model name present in `model-list.csv`. As there are 2900+ items in the `List.csv` and about 150 items in `model-list.csv` file, I was planning to achieve this using a bash script, which is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="List.csv"
file2="model-list.csv"
outfile="List_out.csv"
stagingfile="List-staging.csv"

rm -f "$outfile" "$stagingfile"

while read line
do
        ModelNo=`echo "$line"|awk -F',' '{print $2}'`
        ModelName=`echo "$line"|awk -F',' '{print $3}'`


        cat "$file1"|grep ",$ModelNo," > "$stagingfile"
        if [ -s "$stagingfile" ]
        then

                while read line1
                do
                        NewLine=`echo "$line1"|sed "s/,${ModelNo},/,${ModelName},/g"`
                        echo "$NewLine" >> "$outfile"

                done < "$stagingfile"
                rm -f "$stagingfile"
        fi

done < "$file2"
```

When above script is executed, the `"$outfile"` contains almost 40-50 additional entries as compared to the `List.csv`.

Anything wrong with the script?

Comment: What is the actual output? That should make it easier to debug.

Comment: As I said, the file to be handled is too large to debug. I could just see number of added entries to the resulting file. `List.csv` has 2914 entries and `$outfile` has 2957 of them.

Comment: You could put some of the entries that you weren't expecting in your question. If you don't know which ones shouldn't be there I suggest you trim down both files until the number is manageable.

Comment: Yes. That can be done. I will have to check for this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Would a Perl solution be acceptable? This is possible in bash, I'd probably do it with associative arrays but it is trivial in Perl.

Comment: Yes. Perl will also be acceptable. But Bash is the preferred one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F',|, ' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3} NR>FNR{$8=a[$8];print}' OFS=',' "$file2" "$file1"
```

This reads model-list.csv, storing all the models and their descriptions into an string-indexed array (eg `a["Z800"] == "HP Z800 Workstation"`). Then it reads through the list data, replacing each model with the description string from the array.

Explanation:

- `-F',|, '`  - this sets the field separator using a regex pattern, in this case the field separator will be either a single comma, or a single comma and a single space.
- `NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3}` - NR is an awk internal variable which keeps track of the total number of rows read since the program began. FNR is similar, but keeps track of the number of rows of the *current file* which have been read. So `NR==FNR` is an awk idiom which means "if this is the first file to be read", and the associated action is `a[$2]=$3` which saves the value of field 3 in the array `a`, with the string index being set to the value of field 2.
- `NR>FNR{$8=a[$8];print}'` - similar to the previous, but this time operates only on files other than the first to be read. For each line, we use the value of field 8 as the index to look up the value in the array, then re-assign field 8 to the array value. Finally, the whole line is printed .
- `OFS=',' "$file2" "$file1"` - sets the output field separator to a comma (default is space), then reads in 2 files in the specified order.

Comment: Are you sure about the delimiter? You mentioned a `|` (pipe) here. Or should it be a comma?

Comment: @MandarShinde `-F',|, '` means that the delimiter is either a comma `,` or a comma followed by a space `, `. The pipe is part of the `-F` option.

Comment: This is a more elegant solution rather than the bash script solution. :)

Comment: @MandarShinde - you can use regex patterns as the field separator - see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html (in this case, as Igeorget correctly commented, the field separator is either a single comma or a comma followed by a space, due to the differing nature of your input files).

Comment: @JoshJolly- So, the entire piece of code I have mentioned in the question can be replaced by a single command. Isn't it ?

Comment: Potentially, yes. You should test my answer thoroughly though. :)

Comment: Worked absolutely fine! Can you please elaborate what `'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3} NR>FNR{$8=a[$8];print}' OFS=',' "$file2" "$file1` in this `awk` command exactly does? Is it a kind of `if-elseif` statement?

Comment: I have edited to explain, but generally in awk a condition followed by an action in braces means if the condition is met, the action takes place.

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- Bash is a terrible language for database emulation. Are you sure you cannot use a relational database for this?
- Avoid [useless uses of `cat`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html). You can do `grep ",$ModelNo," "$file1"`.
- You can do `while IFS=, read -r _ ModelNo ModelName _` to avoid the `awk` lines.
- In Bash you can do `my_command <<< "$variable"` instead of `echo "$variable" | my_command`.
- You should use `$(my_command)` instead of `` `my_command` `` for readability.
- `grep -F` will search for literal strings.
- You can check the exit code of `grep` to see if it found anything. That should be faster than checking the file size.

Comment: @l0b0- I am having two options to deal with this issue: Use `Perl` or use `BASH`. I preferred to select the later. Thanks for the notes.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, assuming a bash version >= 4, you can do this very easily using [associative arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## declare models as an associative array
declare -A models

## read the 1st file, load the Value => Model pair
## pairs into the models array. Note that I'm setting bash's
## Input Field Separator ($IFS) to comma (,) and that I first pass
## the file through sed to remove the spaces after the commas.
## For more on why I'm using <() instead of a pipe, see 
## http://stackoverflow.com/q/9985076/1081936
while IFS=, read -r man val mod; 
do 
    models["$val"]="$mod" 
done <  <(sed  's/, /,/g' "$1") 


## Read the second file. I am defining 9 variables, 8 for
## the first 8 fields, up to the model and $rest for the rest of 
## the fields, up to the end of the line.
while IFS=',' read -r loc ip host dom dnam user manu model rest; 
do
   printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$loc" "$ip" "$host" "$dom" \
          "$dnam" "$user" "$manu" "${models[$model]}" "$rest";
done <  <(sed  's/, /,/g' "$2")
```

#### Caveats:

1. This will fail on 1st line of the specific `List.csv` you posted because 
   `model-list.csv` has `Model Name` where `List.csv` has `Model`. This means tat there will be no match for `${models[$model]}` on the first line. You can fix this either by editing the header of one of the files so that the field names are identical or by using this version instead:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   declare -A models
   while IFS=, read -r man val mod; 
   do 
       models["$val"]="$mod" 
   done <  <(sed  's/, /,/g' "$1") 
   ## Set up a counter to hold the line numbers
   c=0;

   while IFS=',' read -r loc ip host dom dnam user manu model rest; 
   do
       ## Increment the line number
       (( c++ ));
       ## If this is the 1st line, print
       if [ "$c" -eq "1" ]; then 
       printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$loc" "$ip" "$host" "$dom" \
           "$dnam" "$user" "$manu" "$model" "$rest";
      else
       printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$loc" "$ip" "$host" "$dom" \
           "$dnam" "$user" "$manu" "${models[$model]}" "$rest";
       fi
   done <  <(sed  's/, /,/g' "$2")
   ```
2. This assumes that your file is as simple as you show, that *all* fields are defined by commas and that no fields can contain commas.

---

In Perl this could of course be done much more simply:

```
perl -F',\s*' -lane '$k{$F[1]}=$F[2]; next if $#F < 4; s/$F[7]/$k{$F[7]}/; print' model-list.csv List.csv
```

#### Explanation

- `-F` sets the field delimiter (here a `,` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters) which is used with `-a` which automatically splits each input line into the `@F` array.
- `-l` turns on automatic removal of the `\n` at the end of each line and also adds an implicit `\n` to each `print` statement.
- `-n` means read the input file line by line and apply whatever script was passed with `-e` to it.
- `$k{$F[1]}=$F[2]` : this populates the has `%k` where the 2nd field of each line is the key and the value is the 3nd field. This is only relevant for the `model-list.csv` but will also be run for `List.csv`. This can safely be ignored as long as `List.csv` will never contain an 8th field that is also present as a 2nd field in `model-list.csv`
- `next if $#F < 4` : read the next line if this one has less than 4 fields. This is so as the final `print` does not print the lines of `model-list.csv`
- `s/$F[7]/$k{$F[7]}/; print` : substitute the 8th field of the current line with whatever is stored in the `%k` hash for that field and print the line.